# Effectively fetching large number of tuples from Solr

Tags: mysql, solr, batch-processing

I am stuck in a rather tricky problem. I am implementing a feature in my website, wherein, a person get all the results matching a particular criteria. The matching criteria can be anything. However, for the sake of simplicity, let's call the matching criteria as 'age'. Which means, the feature will return all the students names, from database (which is in hundreds of thousands) with the student whose age matches 'most' with the parameter supplied, on top.

My approaches:
1- I have a Solr server. Since I need to implement this in a paginated way, I would need to query Solr several times (since my solr page size is 10) to find the 'near-absolute' matching student real-time. This is computationally very intensive. This problem boils down to effectively fetching this large number of tuples from Solr.

2- I tried processing it in a batch (and by increasing the solr page size to 100). This data received is not guaranteed to be real-time, when somebody uses my feature. Also, to make it optimal, I would need to have data learning algos to find out which all users are 'most likely' to use my feature today. Then I'll batch process them on priority. Please do remember that number of users are so high that I cannot run this batch for 'all' the users everyday.


On one hand where I want to show results real-time, I have to compromise on performance (hitting Solr multiple times, thus slightly unfeasible), while on the other, my result set wouldn't be real-time if I do a batch processing, plus I can't do it everyday, for all the users.
Can someone correct my seemingly faulty approaches?
Solr indexing is done on MySQL db contents.

Comment: You are not really talking about [tag:batch-file], are you? please consider to correct the tags accordingly (perhaps you meant [tag:batch-processing] which is something completely different?)... thanks!

Comment: Oh. Yeah. Removed it. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your users are not interested in 100K results. They only want the top-10 (or top-100 or a similar low number) results, where the person's age is closest to a number you supply.

This sounds like a case for Solr function queries: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries. For the age example, that would be something like `sort=abs(sub(37, age)) desc, score desc`, which would return the persons with age closest to 37 first and prioritize by score in case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is using solr cursors which will enable you to paginate effectively through large resultsets [Solr cursors or deep paging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results)

Comment: The main problem is, in order to fetch "best results" I would need to query Solr for all the data present. Which means, I would hit Solr hundredths of times, for each user. Computationally, this is very intensive.